# Magnetic field at end of a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I've seen questions about the magnetic field of a current carrying solenoid, but suppose you have a finite wire of length $L$ with current $I$. Is there some expression for the magnetic field at a distance $R$ from the end along the long axis?

Comment: If you want the current to be constant along the wire, then the wire must be in a loop. Otherwise, there will be charge accumulating at the end and just saying "the current is $I$" does not determine the system (eventually there will be no more charge to move around and the current will vanish, for example).

Comment: The question is written in the same formalism as the finite wire whose field radially is determined using Biot-Savart. I suppose you can imagine you have a piece of equipment on the end which is being powered by the current and whose own magnetic field is negligible.